# How do I integrate two separate Google Analytics accounts such that one account tracks a subpage of the main page that the other account tracks?

Tags: google-analytics, drupal-7

Another person has a google analytics watch on a page and all the first level subpages, however the page I want to track is a subpage of a subpage (second level).  How do I apply my tracking code to collect information on the page I want without interfering with the other account's data collection? Working in drupal 7.

Comment: The best way would probably to ask that person to create a data view for you that filters out everything but your subpage; the permissions system in GA would allow to give you only access to that single view. Rather easier than fiddling with two sets of GA codes (this assumes that  two people tracking the same website are on speaking terms, but that does seem too far fetched).

Comment: We are haha. Thanks maybe this seems like the simplest option.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add multiple instances of analytics.js GA tracking code:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en

You can create static blocks out of GA embeds and use block properties to set on what page what block should appear or use some advanced module, like context to fine tune appearing of that block.

Or you can place the code into html template directly and use good old (and ugly) if condition to show embed code only to some pages.